# Angular Js : Clicking a button selecting all buttons in ng-Repeat instead of one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am clicking on a button (among many added by ng-Repeat in a div block) and all buttons get their "active" class added instead of only that particular one button only which is being clicked, turning all buttons red from blue. (Active class adds background:"red".)

HTML:

```
<button ng-repeat="x in diseaselist" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="clicking(diseaselist)" ng-class="{active:diseaselist.active}">{{x.name}}</button>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.diseaselist = [{name:"Allergy"},{name:"Arthrites"},{name:"Vomiting"},{name:"Asthma"},{name:"BackPain"}{name:"Malaria"}]

$scope.clicking = function(e){
        e.active = !e.active;
    }
```

CSS:

```
button.active{background:red;color:white;}
```

I only want the button which is clicked to have "active" class added, and turn to red (by CSS).

Comment: The button clicked must only get "active" class added, but here all buttons in ng-repeat are getting the "active" class added instead of that clicked one only.

Comment: You're passing to your click the entire `diseaselist` when probably you don't want to be doing that.

Comment: You should pass x and not diseaselist as parameter to clicking...

Comment: Change  ng-click="clicking(diseaselist)" to  ng-click="clicking(x)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `ng-click="clicking(diseaselist)"` but from what I see there `diseaselist` is all the buttons, you need to use `x` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Please check working example: [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/GbjuwreYfMHPrF3z3pWU?p=preview)

HTML

```
  <button ng-repeat="x in diseaselist" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="clicking($index)" ng-class="{active: active == $index}">{{x.name}}</button>
```

Controller :

```
 $scope.name = 'World';
 $scope.diseaselist = [{
    name: "Allergy"
 }, {
    name: "Arthrites"
 }, {
    name: "Vomiting"
 }, {
    name: "Asthma"
 }, {
    name: "BackPain"
 }, {
    name: "Malaria"
 }];

 $scope.clicking = function(index) {
    $scope.active = index
 };
```